# Hide user input in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am currently writing a small guessing game where one player chooses a door to hide a ghost behind and the second player guesses one of three doors to walk through. If he hits a ghost he loses the game. If not, he may proceed.

Now, I looked up several options to hide the input from the player hiding the ghosts, so that the other player can't see behind which door the ghost is hidden. 
As I am working with Pycharm, and my work will be reviewed in Pyhcarm too, I need something, that does work within the Pycharm console without the installation of additional packages.

One option to "hide" the input is to print a bunch of blank lines immediatly after the input. Works, somewhat, but isn't pretty. The "os.system('cls')" solution doesn't work either, because it's not the windows console.
I thought, maybe there is an option to just not show what the ghostplayer is typing in? Like you have on Linux passwords. It just stays blank but catches the input and uses it.

Is there a neat way to achieve this? Haven't found anything yet, but appreciate a link to an already existing discussion I might have looked over as well as suggestions to try out.

Cheers!

EDIT:
To clarify: I am not looking for a method to clear/hide the input in the console, as I wrongly called it earlyier, but the "run"-window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear PyCharm Run Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241268/clear-pycharm-run-window)