# Clear PyCharm Run window without using mouse

Tags: pycharm

I would like to be able to clear the Run console in PyCharm without using a mouse.

I have set the *'clear all'* button as per:

[Clear PyCharm Run Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241268/clear-pycharm-run-window)

But regrettably this requires you to select the console (*from the editor*) before it will work.

Is there an option to allow clearing of the console via a short-cut key from the editor without first having to select the console window?

And if not, is there a hotkey short-cut to toggle between the editor and the console?