# Is there any function which clears pycharm output screen?

Tags: python, pycharm

os.system('cls') doesn't work. It just simply puts a square box at end of output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241268/clear-pycharm-run-window

Comment: @Klaus D  I have seen that question before. Although there is workaround mentioned in answer to that questiojn using pyautogui. I wanted to know if method exists or not. Maybe there exists an library for pycharm console which I don't know of

Comment: Library requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Klaus D Ok I didn't knew that

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation  of `os.system` function, it says, `execute the command in a subshell`.

```
def system(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Execute the command in a subshell. """
    pass
```

That means, your main console is receiving the output of `cls` command run in subconsole ada