# How can I clear terminal in Pycharm

Tags: python, function, terminal, pycharm

I am beginner in Python and I write a code which is looping and requesting html data from a webpage. Then I am printing that data. But Pycharm terminal print every time when it's get the data. So I think I can use time.sleep(5) function because I need a couple of seconds to read the output. But when the next output came, it's writing to below of the last output and my terminal goes down and down. So I think, if I can clear my terminal's output part in Pycharm, right before I print the results it would shown like it changes simultaneously. So how can I code that, is there any code or module to do that in Pycharm.

Comment: Here is the same question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47367480/13714686

Comment: Output could be suspended in the Run tool window: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stopping-and-pausing-applications.html#suspend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are printing only one line of data, the easiest way to update the output is to use `'\r'`, i.e. the carriage return character, to return to the start of the line.

Single line example:

```
import time

for x in range(1,10):
    print('Replace the number on a single line: {}\r'.format(x), end="")
    time.sleep(2)
```

However, if your data consist of multiple lines, you need a Python module such as [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Multiple lines example:

```
import curses
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()

    try:
        for i in range(10):
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'Replace the numbers on multiple lines')
            stdscr.addstr(1, 0, 'Line ONE:' + str(i))
            stdscr.addstr(2, 0, 'Line TWO:' + str(i))
            stdscr.refresh()
            time.sleep(0.5)
    finally:
        curses.echo()
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.endwin()
```